# Tracing group-level and position in LuaTeX

Tags: tex-core, luatex

I am absolutely new to LuaTeX and I have few questions about it. First of all
I learned that in LuaTeX it is possible to trace all TeX tokens with `token filter' callback. Is it possible to get some additional information in callback functions like current positions in input file and current group-level. What I am achieving to do is to write  callback function which looks like:

```
\directlua{
  function foo ()
    t = token.get_next()
    if someTestFunction(t) then
       poz = currentPositionTexEyesAreLookingAtSourceFile()
       level = currentGroupLevel()
       mode = isMathMode()
       table.insert(someTable, {poz, level, mode})
    end
  end
  callback.register('token_filter',foo)
}
```

Comment: You pose a number of not exactly interconnected questions related to LuaTeX. On this site you're more likely to get usable answers if you limit a posting to a specific question. And, when creating postings, it's really helpful to post minimum (working or nonworking) examples that show what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: What are session variables?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the title now that the question is focussed on a specific issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, all these items are available from inside the `token_filter`
callback.
Some of them, however, require a bit of preparation.

## Summary

To address the individual parts of your question:

- You can “trace” all tokens that pass TeX’s mouth using a combination
  of the `token_filter` and the `token` library.
  However, since this implies at least one call to the C API for each
  and every token, it is also quite inefficient.
  I doubt this approach beats `\tracingall` with respect to
  practicality so whatever you actually want to accomplish, it might
  not be what were looking for in the first place.
- The current nesting depth can be queried using the register
  `tex.currentgrouplevel` which corresponds to the eTeX primitive
  `\currentgrouplevel`.
- In order to test for math mode, TeX’s internal nesting stack
  (`tex.nest`) must be accessed.
  `tex.nest.ptr` contains the stack pointer so that
  `tex.nest [tex.nest.ptr]` returns the top of the stack (current
  state).
  If the field `mathstyle` is nonnegative then we are in fact in math
  mode.
  Additionally, inline and display math can be distinguished by
  checking whether the field `mode` is negative.
  (Theoretically the `mode` field alone should suffice for detecting
  math mode -- `\ifmmode` is implemented that way -- but it seems the
  values given in the reference are incorrect.
  Anyways, consult
  [the source](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/nesting.w?view=markup&revision=4442&root=luatex)
  for further details.)
- Tracing input files and line numbers requires more effort.
  Since that kind of information is not directly available through the
  engine we have to manage it ourselves.
  Luckily, Luatex offers all the necessary prerequisites:
  for tracking the lines in the main input file you can use the
  `process_input_buffer` callback.
  Also, thanks to the `open_read_line` callback you have precise
  control over how TeX files are read.
  (The latter itself should be enough on its own when using a startup
  script.  I didn’t test that, though.)

## Example

Here is a demo that combines all of the above:
https://gist.github.com/phi-gamma/6745931 .
The result is a table with information about collected tokens:

[image: Typeset result]

The TeX file defines a couple user level macros.
The first two control the callback state:

```
\enabletokenpos [<number>]  %% enable position tracking
\disabletokenpos            %% disable
```

Lines of the main file will be counted starting with the line where
`\enabletokenpos` occurs.
It takes one **mandatory** argument, namely the the *current line
number*.
To my knowledge the input line at that point cannot be automatically
determined except by using a separate initialization script which would
be outside the scope of the question at hand.

Then there are macros for accessing the current state:

```
\printcurrentfile      %% name of the file being read
\printcurrentpos       %% position in the file being read
\printcurrentfilepos   %% name and position in the customary “<name>:<line>” format
```

Obviously, the callbacks must be in place for them to work.

Tracing is controlled though these macros:

```
\collecttoken          %% add a single token to the tracing table
\startcollecttokens    %% start adding tokens (environment)
\stopcollecttokens     %% stop adding tokens
```

Caution when using the environment:
due to multi-level expansion it will blow up the resulting table pretty
quick.
It is smart enough to not include itself, though.

Finally, in order to output the content of the token collection you need
another macro:

```
\collectedtokens
```

It builds a simple table and prints it in the document.

## Notes

Tracking files is restricted to input (i.e. TeX) files.
Other files touched during a TeX rund -- Lua code, bitmaps, encodings,
and the likes -- are unaffected.
The table `file_stack` helps keeping track of the line numbers inside
individual files.
Both the `process_input_buffer` and the `open_read_file` callback
are used.
This is necessary in order to achieve a correct line count since the
current implementation allows for the Lua code to be loaded while the
document is being processed.
As mentioned above, it should be possible to avoid this by using an
initialization script to install the `open_read_line` filter before
the main input is opened.

The function that is hooked into the `token_filter` comes in two
variants:
`grabtoken()` will consume a single token, add it to the collection,
and remove itself from the callback.
`grabtokens()` (plural) is basically the same function, but it will
remain in place until it disabled by calling `stopcollecting()`.
As a goodie, it will refrain from collecting any token after it
encounters the control sequence `\stopcollecttokens` lest we pollute
the collection with unwanted items.

Tokens are added as a table with the following keys:

- `filename` the name of the input file where the token was
  encountered in;
- `position` the line number of that input file;
- `grouplevel` value of `tex.currentgrouplevel`;
- `mathmode` positive if encountered inside display math, negative if
  in inline math, *false* otherwise;
- `csname` the associated control sequence, if appropriate;
- `token` the token table as returned by `token.get_next()`; the
  meanings of the values are explained in the reference.

E. g. `\input` looks like this:

```
{
  ["csname"]="input",
  ["file"]="tokenposition.tex",
  ["grouplevel"]=2,
  ["mathmode"]=false,
  ["position"]=32,
  ["token"]={ 119, 0, 3360 },
},
```

Comment: Has `open_read_line` become `open_read_file` these days?